# How to get dynamic data from the text box using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to get data from a text box using dynamic jquery . it should be like if i click on the update button it should open an alert dialog box with the value entered in the text box in the corresponding text box but my program isnt wokrking .Firstly it isnt getting data from the text box and secondly it isnt getting data from the corrresponding text box

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table tr td input[type='button']").click(function() {
$(this).closest('tr').find('td').first().find('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', false);
 });
});
//===========================================

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.chkUpdate').on('click', function(){
  // var serverName =document.getElementById("servername").value;
  // var app = document.getElementById("app").value;
   //var other = $(this).text();
    var other = $(this).text();
    alert(other);    
  });
}); 

</script>
</head>
<table>
<tr> 
    <td> <input type="text" disabled value="Edit"/> </td>      
    <td> <input type="button" name="test" value="Edit"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="submit" name="test" class="chkUpdate" value="update"/> </td>

</tr>
<tr> 
    <td> <input type="text" name="test" disabled value="Edit"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="button" name="test" value="Edit"/> </td> 
   <td> <input type="submit" name="test" class="chkUpdate" value="update"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> <input type="text" name="test" disabled value="Edit"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="button" name="test" value="Edit"/> </td> 
    <td> <input type="submit" name="test" class="chkUpdate" value="update"/> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: with textbox use val() not text()

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef no luck it is giving the value of that field ie update and no the text i entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
       $(this).parent().parent().find('td').first().find('input[type="text"]').attr('disabled', false);
       alert($(this).parent().parent().find('td').first().find('input[type="text"]').val());
 });
});
```

or you can use something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
           $(this).parent().prev().find('input[type="text"]').attr('disabled', false);
           alert($(this).parent().prev().find('input[type="text"]').val());
     });
    });
```

Comment: thanks man this at least helps me to get data from the text box and display in alert

Answer (score 0):

Basically, from what I can see, your check update function is trying to get the text (value) from *`this`* which is the update button.  You need to create some method that the button can determine which input/text needs updating.

The code you use in the input button is pretty slick and you could use something similar in the check update submit button.

Also, a smaller note, since both event handlers are inside document/ready code, make it a single document ready.